# /time set night and /weather rain are not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In all of my worlds, whenever I do `/time set night` it doesn't work,  and instead stays daytime. Also once the game reaches the point were it would turn to night it goes back to the start of a day. So I have no way of making it night time. I have the same problem with the `/weather rain` command, whenever I enter this the weather stays clear. Also when I enter a command like /time set night it says set time to 13000 but as I said it stays daytime

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Have you got any command blocks on a timer to make sure it stays day, or to make sure it doesn't rain? And for the `/weather rain` one, is your world superflat because for me weather does not work in superflat worlds.

Comment: We need more information, i.e. logfiles, minecraft version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have optifine, this answer is for you.

I was looking through the Minecraft menu, and I figured it out. Here are the steps to fix it.

1. Go to the Game Menu
2. Select Options
3. Go to Video Settings
4. Select Other
5. Turn Weather to on, and time to Default.

Comment: You shouldn't provide answers that are based off assumptions.

Comment: Why there are two downvotes? In the question there was no details about the conditions. And in my case this answer worked. Thanks @Sam

Answer (score -3):

If you're playing Vanilla Minecraft (not a server or modded), you will need to do `/time set <number>` and for weather it's `/toggledownfall`.